# Overflow scroll is not working as expected during % width

Tags: html, css, web, sass

I am having trouble to make container to take certain width using percentage value. When using max-width to certain % it is overflowing out of the window. If i use fixed width it's working as expected.
As i want make it responsive i want to use % value. How can i achieve the result?

HTML:

```
<div class="select-address">
   <div class="address-radio-container radio-element-container">
      <div class="address-radio">
         <div class="address-radio-element radio-element">
            <input id="address-tmirddv" name="address" type="radio" class="radio-input" value="cash"> 
            <div class="radio-input-check"></div>
            <div class="label-container">
               <label for="address-tmirddv" class="radio-label">
                  <p class="type">Radio</p>
                  <p class="details">Radio</p>
               </label>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="address-radio-element radio-element">
            <input id="address-y4x3jr" name="address" type="radio" class="radio-input" value="dp"> 
            <div class="radio-input-check"></div>
            <div class="label-container">
               <label for="address-y4x3jr" class="radio-label">
                  <p class="type">Radio</p>
                  <p class="details">Radio</p>
               </label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
  .address-radio {
    width: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    .address-radio-element {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 12px;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background-color: $color-grey-lighter;
      .label-container {
        width: 224px;
        margin-left: 7px;
      }
    }
  }
```

While using % value in width:
[image]

While using px value: (Want to achieve result like this using %)

[image]

Comment: Regarding my code...
My question was only about the radio selection div's content --- Why it is overflowing if i use % value. And i didn't need any row / col. Cause setting 'display: inline-block' in child element is making them to stay in a row.

Comment: sorry I would like to help but in this I case need to reproducer the scenario to help find a solution . did you try flex?

Comment: Yes. But it's outside the 'select-address' div. My question is only about this portion. In first line of css if i use px value for width getting expected result. But if i use % value it is going outside of the window. I am trying to find out why it's happening

Comment: must set width : calc(100% - xxx);
xxx = sum of radio items margin+padding+border-size

Answer (score 0):

When you set width 100%. You most remove margin,padding and border of this div. If set padding,margi,border then you must write like this:
Width : calc (100% - 26px)

Comment: Tried the approach. Sorry it didn't workout in this case.